# i want to count firestore collections that have a same field value and count them in a table?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have a list of users in the firestore
each user have his own Country
i want to count the number of users that have a same country and list them in a table like this

for example i have 3 users have Tunisia as a country, 1 user have Germany,

| Country Name | Total users |
| --- | --- |
| Tunisia | 3 |
| Germany | 1 |

my flutter code:

```
child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 500,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(),
      child: DataTable(
        columns: [
          DataColumn(label: Text(
              'Country',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
          )),
          DataColumn(label: Text(
              'Total',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
          )),
        ],
        rows: [
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('Stephen')),
            DataCell(Text('Actor')),
          ]),
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('John')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

[image: Firebase firestore]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.